# MVC3 Routes with Different Parameter Types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am struggling to get my head around routing in MVC3.

Previously I have generally just avoided the whole area and stuck with ugly old `?id=1&foo=bar` type urls. Not nice.

I have 4 routes defined thusly

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", "{controller}/{action}/{PageNumber}/{PostsPerPage}", new { controller = "blog", action = "list", PageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional, PostsPerPage = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("Code", "{controller}/{action}/{title}", new { });
routes.MapRoute("Id", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
```

I have tried to order them from most specific to least.

The first 'blog' route works fine and I can use a URL like `/blog/list/2/5` and it maps correctly to my controller.

The default route at the bottom is also working as I would expect.

However if I have action methods like this:

```
public ActionResult BarX(int id)
{
    //some stuff
}

public ActionResult BarY(string title)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

I would expect it to use the third route and produce a URL like `/foo/barX/3`.

Yet if I use

```
@Html.ActionLink("TEST1", "barX", "foo", new { id = 3 }, null)
```

the URL generated is

```
/foo/barx?id=3
```

Similarly the URL generated for

```
@Html.ActionLink("TEST2", "barY", "foo", new { title = "test" }, null)
```

is

```
/foo/bary?title=test
```

So I guess my question is: why are they producing URLs with the old `?id=` syntax and not `/foo/barx/3`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of your routes are basically the same. They are

```
{controller}/{action}/{param}/{param}
```

I say the same because the routing engine would not understand the difference between `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and `{controller}/{action}/{title}`

and the route engine would really just see

```
{controller}/{action}/{PageNumber}/{PostsPerPage}
```

and confuse all the routes with the first one.

---

Once the route engine sees your almost generic `{optional}/{optional}/{optional}/{optional}/` route at the top, anything with 4 or fewer elements can fit it so it goes no further.

---

If, on the other hand, your routes had distinctive beginnings, rather than generic `{Controller}`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Blog/{PageNumber}/{PostsPerPage}", new { controller = "blog", action = "list", PageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional, PostsPerPage = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("Code", "Code/{title}", new { controller = "code", action = "list", title = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now, every time the routing engine sees `Blog/...` it understands that only 1 route can match. With all others, it will move on looking for a match. Whenever it sees `Code/...`, again only 1 route is a match. And Default will handle anything like `{Controller}/{Action}/{id}` that doesn't have `Blog` or `Code` as a first route param.

Comment: "All of your routes are basically the same." +1 - nail on the head.