# ASP.NET WebApi Routes and parameters types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have read many articles and similar questions but none of those decisions do not fit me.
I have 3 methods:

```
public string GetA()
{
   return "Hello from GetA";
}
public string GetB(int id)
{
   return "Hello from GetB";
}
public string GetC(sting all)
{
   return "Hello from GetC";
}
```

I need to configure route like:

```
1.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/
2.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/all
3.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/1
4.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/1/all
```

How can I implement it? 
I know this may be a duplicate ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30641012/5246440), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15605945/4275342), [3](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3029/different-types-of-routing-in-aspnet-mvc)), but I need help with it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @CliffBurton Did you read the question? I know and a wrote "I know this may be a duplicate (1, 2, 3), but I need help with it." and there are a links. Link number 3 is the same. Please read the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other solution is to add static segment to route:

```
1.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/
2.http://localhost:63087/api/all/Test/
3.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/1
4.http://localhost:63087/api/all/Test/1
```

Implementation:

```
    public string GetA()
    {
        return "Hello from GetA";
    }
    public string GetB(int id)
    {
        return "Hello from GetB";
    }

    [Route("api/all/{controller}/{id}")]
    [Route("api/all/{controller}")]
    public string GetC(int id= 0)
    {
        return "Hello from GetC";
    }
```

Route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "AllRoute",
       routeTemplate: "api/full/{controller}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

Comment: I like this solution. An its work. Thanks. Thanks. Thanks

Comment: But now I have another problem with inheritence. Because Route attributes not inherited. Can U help me?

Comment: Where do you use inheritance?

Comment: See [MVC Attribute Routes & Route Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23431043/4275342)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
       {           
                config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
                config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/Test",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "GetA"}
                );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "WithID",
                    routeTemplate: "api/Test/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "GetB", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ALL",
                    routeTemplate: "api/Test/all",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "GetC"}
                );
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not help me. `http://localhost:58052/api/test` - Ok, `http://localhost:58052/api/test/all` - The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'..., `http://localhost:58052/api/test/1` - Ok, `http://localhost:58052/api/test/1/all` - HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Configure your routes like this

```
http://localhost:63087/api/Test
http://localhost:63087/api/Test/1
http://localhost:63087/api/Test/1/all
```

Something like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/Test",
                defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "GetA"}
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Route2",
                routeTemplate: "api/Test/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "GetB" }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Route3",
                routeTemplate: "api/Test/{id)/{all}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "GetC"}
            );
```

Comment: No, it is not my routes. Please see the question. I have 4 routes

Comment: You cannot have two routes with same parameter count. Event if you have so the route engine will consider only the first route. So, both 2 and 3 cant be achieved at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why I create questions. I need a solution to this poblemy

Comment: Try to achieve the functionality of 2 and 4 with the same route. For `http://localhost:63087/api/Test/all` try using some default value for id (say 0 or -1) which means for all id's. Now your 2nd route becomes `http://localhost:63087/api/Test/0/{all}` and 4th becomes `http://localhost:63087/api/Test/{id}/{all}`

Comment: Thank you, this solution is working. What other ways can you offer me? Because 0 is not very nice

Answer (score 0):

So, you can not have two routes with same parameter count.

```
2.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/all
3.http://localhost:63087/api/Test/1
```

In this way, you can use in all your methods parameters type `string`:

```
public string GetA()
{
   return "Hello from GetA";
}
public string GetB(string id, string all = "")
{
   if (id.Equals("all") || all.Equals("all"))
   {
       return "Hello all from GetB";
   }
   return string.Format("Hello {0} from GetB", id);
}
```

Route config:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "RouteWithParam",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{all}",
        defaults: new { all = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it won't be proper to use string type for ID values

Comment: Ok. It is just one of the possible solution