# What is the best practice to route related entities in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, related-content

I'm working with entities in WebApi application that have a linked entities.
For example:

- Entity Street has the following related resource: `City`
- Entity `City` has: `Region`, `CityType`
- Entity `Person`: `Address`, `Nationality`, `Position`, `Catalog`, `Documents` ...

How can I proper route related entities?

Before I used OData request like: `http://localhost:3761/api/City?$expand=CityType,Region` for `City` and `http://localhost:3761/api/Person?$expand=Address,Nationality,Documents,Catalog` for `Person`.
But most client do not know which exist related objects. And they want to add some parameter to request that will get entity with all linked data.

Example `http://localhost:3761/api/Person/full` or `http://localhost:3761/api/Person/2/full` for Person with `ID` = 2.

I tried to implement it but [I have problem with routing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32112653/5246440). 
So as I have a base api controller then attributes is not inherited to my child controller and as a result it doesn't work.

Could you please suggest me what is the best practice to route related entities?

P.S: Sorry for my English and let me know if something is not clear. 

Thanks

Comment: can  anyone help me? Please write at least comment

Comment: I need your help. please

Answer (score 0):

Look at how Trello has organized their API [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/api/)

They allow one level of pivoting and the posibility to declare what kind of data your are interested in. There have default fields which you get returned unless you specify a list of fields from a valid list.

Example:
GET: api/1/cards/card id/members  ([Options](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-members))

In your case this would transform into something like this:

http://localhost:3761/api/people/2?&fields=address,nationality,position,catalog

Comment: Thanks but I know hot to return fields. I ask about related entities (object in object). I found similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620089/asp-net-webapi-creating-one-level-json. But there is not answer that help me

Comment: In my case `api/Person?$expand=Address,Nationality,Documents,Catalog` IS NOT a fields this is related entities (using navigation property as Foreign Keys)