# ASP.NET WebAPI Creating one-level JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

There are many related entities in Domain assembly. For example `People` that has navigation properties (Level1) to `FamilyRelations`, `Houses` and `Persons`. Beside this the `Houses` has own nav.prop (Level2) to `Address` and `Address` (Level3) has to `City`, `Street` ... etc. 
[image]
When I set `LazyLoadingEnabled` to true then I'm getting JSON (on the left side in screen) with all related entities.

How can I get only one level of nesting (as on the right side in scree) or set other levels to `NULL` value (because I had setting Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)?

Can I implement it without use `.Include` to each entity?

My class of People:

```
    public class People : BaseEntity
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        public int HouseID { get; set; }

        public int PeopleNumber { get; set; }

        public int? FamilyRelationID { get; set; }            

        //FK to House
        public virtual House Houses { get; set; }
        //FK to Person
        public virtual Person Persons { get; set; }
        //FK to FamilyRelations
        public virtual FamilyRelations FamilyRelations { get; set; }
    }
```

WebAPI config:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new   MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling
             = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

I do not have any solution because I did not have enough experience with it. 
 So, I need your suggestions, advices about it. Sorry for my English and if I have to add more informations, please let me know. Thanks

**UPDATE**
I've tried to add `[JsonIgnore]` or ignore those properties in mapping class but when I do request `get/House` then I need to get field from `Address` without nav.prop and when request `get/People` then I do not nedd `Address`. As a result I can't ingnore it.

Comment: This may help: [How Do I Make JSON.NET Ignore Object Relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21292010/10263)

Answer (score 1):

Never return tracked objects to the controller. Your business logic code (which should not exist in the controller) should map your database aware objects to POCOs. This can be as simple as using

```
var poco = AutoMapper.Map<People>(livePerson)
```

And you setup in your mapping profile to ignore those properties so they're not copied.

Note my automapper-fu is rusty that syntax is rough code.

You want to be very careful with any blind mapping as it opens you up to the [Mass Assignment vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability). This is equally true for going straight to your live tracked objects. If a user sees in their data IsAdmin: false, they might get crafty and post IsAdmin: true. This can be saved to your database with blind assignments.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain to me how should I manage what properties need to ignore in cases when I want to get `People` and `House`? When `People` then need to ignore `Address` of `House` but when `House` then I do not need to ignore `Address`. Sorry if it not clear

Comment: You setup different maps for each situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are look for a way to ignore navigation properties in `json` serialization, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162902/how-can-i-do-json-serializer-ignore-navigation-properties/#32797274) can help and you can ignore navigation properties in `json` serialization by it.